# not able to select drop down in share point site using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

[image]below is the html code

```
<html dir="ltr" __expr-val-dir="ltr" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
<head>
<body onload="javascript:if (typeof(_spBodyOnLoadWrapper) != 'undefined') _spBodyOnLoadWrapper();" scroll="yes">
<form id="aspnetForm" onsubmit="javascript:return WebForm_OnSubmit();" action="/Lists/Bedrifter/NewForm.aspx?RootFolder=%2FLists    %2FBedrifter&ContentTypeId=0x010089708C9D4BD6934C8E5AAD8CA5960372&Source=http%3A%2F%2Fbrbaker%2Eiqubes%2Ecom%2FLists%2FBedrifter    %2FAllItems%2Easpx" method="post" name="aspnetForm">
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=4d6EoZshmx02OmMScHE3DbHlrYbV8g3RhGO1crQQDRnSnV0ocSltu-   h2JR6NPXUrSq6UdfWCYI3o0DJF_ZfaK3a8coA1&t=634605546709717464">
<script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
<script src="/_layouts/datepicker.js" language="javascript">
<script language="javascript">
<script language="javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=Lim-50lYe1ZDrlX4mMFL650sLf8k9DOdc77CA32d5iqCcwZgC0o44-JDQvjWVdOvFNhnh9Rv8ET6IZprG0J0- hy3RwAt6a8wzZYDlicHIDUEUV3EM6jVmf-3rAG4gzDt7vMtWA2&t=ffffffffe0ec361c">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=kzC4QkzPw8VSUFfZJOZJBiUuRCJh8hH4jceOz-aS9SoZHjrHyO0-  qLxFSc_CZdZWHipnmUwdugwDjjJUVkJPeY6Lu2n5NvmKbB5lpZ-yM3GAfcBKWP54a0try64gthczZoxjy1sDHJib8zf8iHnFyopgObE1&t=23ac280b">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/ScriptResource.axd?d=Glp6MnJF7a1dHB7t8aIwFln7LYIjT8Kl_yKq1264_-9QdU3Y7jwHZhcKumPfVlZ3bLuoCPjTZgTerzZfJQex- 7jEIxOZZewN1qSYBhLI3WDJOu1cpD5txPFEu4or9SHjqQ-3ZCDMbq-5NF6lo2Fvf-OSqgUnrMwO8kWZBqN8GlLP10qd0&t=23ac280b">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/WebResource.axd?d=xYoo8lVwQo4Vp8QZN5OAU9ZNIsutUO_7HeMk_xB4mc0J5qXChkZyGSQUm-   GEsHBbkeAr07Gg56nkgPJwAT9UisVxGYs1&t=634605546709717464">
<script type="text/javascript">
<div>
<script type="text/javascript">
<table class="ms-iqubes-body" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ms-globalbreadcrumb" colspan="4">
<td width="3%" valign="middle" style="padding-left:3px; padding-right:6px;">
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr height="100%">
<td>
<table class="iqubes-background" width="100%" height="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<td id="LeftNavigationAreaCell" class="ms-leftareacell" valign="top" height="100%">
<td>
<td class="ms-bodyareacell" valign="top">
<placeholder id="ctl00_MSO_ContentDiv">
<table id="MSO_ContentTable" class="ms-propertysheet" width="100%" height="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ms-bodyareaframe" valign="top" height="100%">
<a name="mainContent"></a>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
<table id="onetIDListForm" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td id="MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5" valign="top">
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" toplevel="">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td valign="top">
<div id="WebPartWPQ5" style="" allowdelete="false" width="100%" haspers="false" webpartid="bac1b910-309d-4e46-47b4-0b8a052b0579">
<span id="part1">
<table id="ctl00_m_g_bac1b910_309d_4e46_47b4_0b8a052b0579_ctl00_toolBarTbltop" class="ms-formtoolbar" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"   cellpadding="2">
<table id="ctl00_m_g_bac1b910_309d_4e46_47b4_0b8a052b0579_ctl00_ctl01_ctl00_toolBarTbl" class="ms-toolbar" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0"  cellpadding="2">
<table class="ms-formtable" width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="margin-top: 8px;">
<tbody>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<tr>
<td class="ms-formlabel" width="190px" valign="top" nowrap="true">
<td class="ms-formbody" width="400px" valign="top">
<span dir="none">
<select id="ctl00_m_g_bac1b910_309d_4e46_47b4_0b8a052b0579_ctl00_ctl04_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup" title="Parent company" name="ctl00$m   $g_bac1b910_309d_4e46_47b4_0b8a052b0579$ctl00$ctl04$ctl15$ctl00$ctl00$ctl04$ctl00$Lookup">
<br>
```

I used almost all method's for selecting drop down as below

```
 new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='ctl00_m_g_bac1b910_309d_4e46_47b4_0b8a052b0579_ctl00_ctl04_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup']"))).selectByVisibleText("Baker Brazil");
```

i tried with id, name etc but i am getting error

org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to find element with xpath =="".

I am using IE 10 to do testing of a  share point site.

Comment: it works fine. Is it under any `frames` ?

Comment: no it is not under a frame but under a td,  <td class="ms-formbody" width="400px" valign="top">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i got the answer i just followed steps in this [blog](http://functionaltestautomation.blogspot.in/2008/12/xpath-in-internet-explorer.html)

```
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//SPAN[@id='part1']/TABLE[3]/TBODY/TR[16]/TD[2]/SPAN")).click();
         driver.findElement(By.xpath("//SPAN[@id='part1']/TABLE[3]/TBODY/TR[16]/TD[2]/SPAN")).sendKeys(Parentcompany);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just give a try with below locator.

```
new Select(driver.findElemet(By.cssSelector("select[title='Parent company']"))).selectByVisibleText("Baker Brazil");
```

Comment: it shows same error Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"select[title='Parent company']"}

Comment: Is it working fine in any other browser? Have you verified locator in firebug? It that unique element with that locator ? Is it in iframe?

Comment: Try with below locator ==>> By.xpath("//td[@id='MSOZoneCell_WebPartWPQ5']//select[contains(@name,Lookup) and @title='Parent company']")

Answer (score 0):

I think the id is auto generated one (usually .net/share point applications do). Try the below code

example:

```
new Select(driver.findElemet(By.xpath("//*[contains(@id='Lookup')]"))).selectByVisibleText("Baker Brazil");
```

Or just check which part of id is getting auto generated and modify the xpath accordingly using xpath functions (`starts-with() or ends-with() or contains()`) as shown in example

Comment: Just found that sharepoint forms uses web tables to align the text and fields. So first you need to get the table and then navigate to particular row and then use the above options (both answers provided by me and @Santoshsarma will work)

Comment: can u guide me to navigate to row as you said .i have added the screen shot

Comment: Posted new answer...check it

Answer (score 0):

I checked in one of the share point application that the form/web table is located in the iframe. This is the reason why you were getting the exception.
Try the below code directly, no need to go for table proceedure

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Add new item")).click();
//give your iframe class name, which will be on top of the topmost table tag
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.className("ms-dlgFrame")));
//use below xpath
Select list = new Select (driver.findElement(By.xpath("//select[@title='Parent Company']")));
list.selectByVisibleText("Baker Brazil");
```

Comment: @bharth , i dont see any frame in the html code.For your reference i have added the full html code.

Comment: when i used below code it is working fine in fire fox but still not working in IE 10. String dropdownXpath = "//table/tbody/tr[4]/td/table/tbody/tr[2]/td[3]/placeholder/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td/div/span/table[3]/tbody/tr[16]/td[2]/span/select";
       WebElement textInDropDown = driver.findElement(By.xpath(dropdownXpath + "[@id='ctl00_m_g_bac1b910_309d_4e46_47b4_0b8a052b0579_ctl00_ctl04_ctl15_ctl00_ctl00_ctl04_ctl00_Lookup']"));
       textInDropDown.click();
       driver.findElement(By.xpath(dropdownXpath)).sendKeys(Parentcompany);

Comment: Hey Pramod,....Sorry...really I am also unable to provide the right answer by referring to your html. Can you try the same xpath (details) using AUIs(advance user interfaces-mouse hover) . Let me know this works or not.